# Add rel="lightbox" to links with .jpg and .gif in them

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, addition

I'm trying to make a simple script that adds rel="lightbox" to links with .jpg or .gif in the href. Can someone help me? I can't see the mistake. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       $('a[href*=".jpg"]').each(function() {
          $('a[href*=".gif"]').each(function() {
              $(this).attr('rel','lightbox'); 
          });
       });

</script>
```

Comment: you filtered .JPGs first and then added `lightbox` attribute to all .GIFs for every .JPG image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're targeting links with href attributes that contain BOTH '.jpg' AND '.gif'.  Try targeting links with href attributes that END WITH EITHER '.jpg' OR '.gif':

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $('a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".gif"]').each(function() {
          $(this).attr('rel','lightbox'); 
       });
</script>
```

*Update*
To run the script when the DOM is ready, attach the function to the domready event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".gif"]').each(function() {
          $(this).attr('rel','lightbox'); 
       });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that as well. When the page loads I check source and there is no rel="lightbox" attribute in my a tags. You know why?

Comment: source code does not keep up with dynamic dom changes - best to use your browser debubgging tools to inspect the elements.

Comment: If you're simply viewing source from the browser you're seeing the code as downloaded prior to the application of any scripts.  Use a developer console like firebug to check the current state of the DOM.

Comment: It seems to be working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/pD53R/ But, make sure that you have it in an onLoad function

Comment: I'm using mozilla developer tool and I still don't see any change. I have jquery loaded too.

Comment: @Keller I updated the code - you should be running this when the DOM is ready.

Comment: I'm not a js/jq expert could someone help me with the onLoad function I tried googling it. Weird syntax to me.

Comment: @Keller Absolutely - glad that I could help!